# Map Texture around Sphere OpenGL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, blender, texture-mapping

I'm trying to map a single texture around a sphere that I exported from Blender. The model looked great in Blender but when I use it in my Android application the texture appears to be mapped to almost every face, not the whole sphere. Any ideas? I am using libGDX on Android.

The setup code:

```
    model = G3dtLoader.loadStillModel(Gdx.files.internal("models/planet.g3dt"), true);

    for(StillSubMesh mesh: model.subMeshes) {
        mesh.mesh.scale(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    }

    G3dExporter.export(model, Gdx.files.local("models/planet.g3d"));
    model = G3dLoader.loadStillModel(Gdx.files.local("models/planet.g3d"));

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("textures/planet1_pot.png"), true);

    bounds = new BoundingBox();
    model.getBoundingBox(bounds);
    float len = bounds.getDimensions().len();

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(60, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(bounds.getCenter().cpy().add(len / 2, len / 2, len / 2));
    cam.lookAt(bounds.getCenter().x, bounds.getCenter().y, bounds.getCenter().z);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 1000;

    renderer = new ImmediateModeRenderer10();
```

The rendering code:

```
    @Override
    public void renderScreen(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        cam.update();
        cam.apply(Gdx.gl10);

        if(texture != null) {
            Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
            Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            texture.bind();
        }

        model.render();

        if(texture != null) {
            Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
            Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
    }
```

Edit:
Here is a screenshot demonstrating my problem:
[image]

Comment: Maybe post a picture of the bad render? AFAIK that only thing that could cause a problem like that would be either a bad model or a bad model loader. I don't have a happy track record with blender model exporting (they are usually broken for me in some way or another), so maybe inspect your model to make sure that it got exported correctly? As long as it's not a binary file maybe put up the model source in your post as well.

Comment: @Tim I added a screenshot of my problem. I was kind of thinking that it was a problem with the export from Blender (I am no expert with Blender by any means haha) so maybe that is it. I might try to create a Sphere manually in code and see if I can get it to render correctly that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this problem out. I re-created my model in Blender following [this link](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/BlenderModels) which says it's deprecated and lacks the screenshots but it helped me out. I ended up just exporting my model as a .obj and the texture now maps to the whole sphere.